# mysql update subquery not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, subquery

mysql update syntax doesn't seem to work when I added the subquery. 
Are there restrictions on subqueries on update syntax?

doesn't work:

```
    update books set imagename ='name' 
    where book_ID='(select book_ID from books order by book_ID desc limit 1)';
```

works:

```
    update books set imagename ='name' 
    where book_ID='101';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does have limits on subqueries using the table being updated.  So yours is not allowed:

```
update books
    set imagename ='name' 
    where book_ID = (select book_ID from books order by book_ID desc limit 1);
```

Instead, you can do:

```
update books
    set imagename ='name' 
    order by book_ID desc
    limit 1;
```

Here is the explanation in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html):

> In general, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table
>   in a subquery. For example, this limitation applies to statements of
>   the following forms:
>
> ```
>     DELETE FROM t WHERE ... (SELECT ... FROM t ...);
>     UPDATE t ... WHERE col = (SELECT ... FROM t ...);
>     {INSERT|REPLACE} INTO t (SELECT ... FROM t ...);
> ```
>
> Exception: The preceding prohibition does not apply if you are using a subquery for the modified table in the FROM clause. Example:
>
> ```
>     UPDATE t ... WHERE col = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM t...) AS _t ...);
>  Here the result from the subquery in the FROM clause is stored as a temporary table, so the relevant rows in t have already been
> ```
>
> selected by the time the update to t takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Try This query.

```
Update books
Set imagename = name"
Where book_ID In (
                Select T1.book_ID
                From books As T1
                Where T1.book_ID = '101'

                )
```